# I have a Toplevel button in tkinker that I want to close the window and then perform a function

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

So far I have created a frame with some functioning buttons/menus. One of my menu buttons opens a new Toplevel window. This new Toplevel window is basically a forum fill out page. At the end of the page is a done button. This done button closes the tkiniter Toplevel window while leaving the root window. I wish to execute lines of code after the button is pressed.

My first idea was to set the done button command to make the window 'withdrawn'. If I do this, it does withdraw the window but if I try to run an if check the check will already have been checked before the button is pressed. The most simple solution to this would be to create a function the withdraws the window and does the other stuff I am wanting, however, when I try to pass a function as the command for the Toplevel done button it does not call the function.

Any advice how to make the button close the window and then perform additional code (Only after the button is pressed) would be greatly appreciated. I have attached the section of code in question below. Thank You in advance for your help. (Side note Computer class is handled in another file). (I am using Python 3.x)

```
def draw_new_computer_entry(self):
    t = Toplevel(self)
    t.resizable(0,0)
    t.wm_title("Solution Center: Add New Computer")
    t.geometry("300x300")
    nameLabel = Label(t, text="Computer Name:")
    nameLabel.place(x=0,y=10)

    a = computer()

    comp_nameEntry = Entry(t, width=30)
    comp_nameEntry.place(master=None, x=100, y=10)
    a.name = comp_nameEntry.get()

    comp_makerEntry= Entry(t,width=30)
    comp_makerEntry.place(x=100, y=50)
    a.maker = comp_makerEntry.get()

    makerLabel= Label(t, text="Maker:")
    makerLabel.place(x=55,y=50)

    graphics_cardEntry= Entry(t, width=30)
    graphics_cardEntry.place(x=100,y=90)
    a.gpu = graphics_cardEntry.get()

    graphics_cardLabel= Label(t, text="Graphics Card:")
    graphics_cardLabel.place(x=15, y=90)

    processorEntry= Entry(t, width=30)
    processorEntry.place(x=100, y=130)
    a.processor = processorEntry.get()

    processorLabel= Label(t, text="Processor:")
    processorLabel.place(x=38, y=130)

    hard_driveEntry= Entry(t, width=30)
    hard_driveEntry.place(x=100, y=170)
    a.hard_drive = hard_driveEntry.get()

    hard_driveLabel= Label(t, text="Hard Drive:")
    hard_driveLabel.place(x=30, y=170)

    ramEntry= Entry(t, width=30)
    ramEntry.place(x=100, y=210)

    ramLabel= Label(t,text="Ram:")
    ramLabel.place(x=65,y=210)
    doneButton = Button(t, text="done", command=t.withdraw)
    doneButton.place(x=265, y=275)
```

Comment: `command` expects function name without `()` and arguments. If you put function with `()` then this function is executed at start and its result is assigned to `command`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is create a function that closes the window and then performs additional code.

Here is a snippet of your code:

```
def donePressed():
    t.withdraw() # Or t.destroy(), depending if you need to open this window again
    # Enter Code Here
    print('code after window close')
doneButton = Button(t, text="done", command=donePressed)
doneButton.place(x=265, y=275)
```